# Creating a clustered network force directed graph with expanded nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, nodes

I need to create a graph same as [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239) but I don't know how to get it to expand all the nodes initially when the svg is first drawn instead of needing a double click to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current implementation requires the list of clusters to expand. So one option is to get the names of all clusters and assemble this list. An alternative option is to reverse the meaning `expand` to denote the collapsed clusters (and rename it accordingly).

I've done the latter in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/4e5dbf8be2c83631a05b).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Lars, it really helped a lot. One more question, is there a way that I can allow the group  to have multiple values? For example I have a json object lik this.{"id": 1,"name": "Emp-1",  "group": {"Department": "18",  "Level": "8", "Office": "44", "Role": "3"}}        
I tried changing the getGroup function but that didn't work

Comment: This example doesn't really support that. I guess you'd need to modify the visualisation fundamentally to show that nodes are members of multiple clusters (or some kind of partial membership?). It's also not clear how this would interact with the collapse/expand, e.g. when you expand a cluster, does it automatically expand all the clusters that any of the nodes in this cluster are members of?

Comment: Okay, so the idea is not to have any collapsed nodes just have hulls around groups and have a couple of radio buttons that showcase each group so basically Department has its own visualization and onClick on the Roles radio the visualization would group by Roles instead.

Comment: Well then all you need to do is modify the `getGroup` function to extract the desired group from the list depending on the state of the visualisation.

Comment: This is how I tries to achieve that and I pass the groupName to the init function each time but it didn't work. function getGroup(n, groupName) { return n.group[groupName]; }

Comment: Can't really tell you what the problem is without seeing a complete example.

Comment: Alright man! I appreciate your help on this. Again, thank you so much.